# set_relationship return array(3) { ["created"]=> int(0) ["failed"]=> int(1) ["deleted"]=> int(0) in sugarcrm wiith soap API

Tags: soap, sugarcrm

**What I have Done?**

I have created a custom module booking  and make a realtionship with accounts (one to many relationship).

data in accounts and booking comes with the help of soap (set_entry) method.

**What I want?**

I  data of relationship field also appear  for that I am using  a set_realtionship method.

here is the my code.

```
 $results = $soapclient->call('set_relationship', array (
    'session' => $session_id,
    'module_name' => 'Accounts',
    'module_id' => $account_id,
    'link_field_name' => 'hotel_booking',
    'related_ids' => array ($htel_booking_id),
    ));

  var_dump($results);
```

it return

```
array(3) {
  ["created"]=>
  int(0)
  ["failed"]=>
  int(1)
  ["deleted"]=>
  int(0)
```

**Account id ,session id , hotel booking id all things are correct.**

**I have also used a different way to set  realtionship but there is also no luc**k...

the code are

```
$rl = array(
    'session' => $session_id,
    'set_relationship_value' => array(
    'module1' => 'Accounts',
    'module1_id' => $account_id,
    'module2' => 'hotel_booking',
    'module2_id' => $htel_booking_id,

    )
);

$resultRel = $soapclient->call('set_relationship',$rl);

print_r($resultRel);
```

this also give me a same out put.

I don`t know where is the problem 
**please help me.**

Comment: the result comes from the soap call is clear that it failed as it given the value 1 to failed.

Comment: Now What can I do please tell me.

Comment: @ajaykumar can you post the result of print_r($rl); here or check it by yourself that is it correct or not.

Comment: thanks for quick response  print_r($rl) working correct.  output is Array
(
    [session] => eaglru5s01qn7mevlmtn46g040
    [set_relationship_value] => Array
        (
            [module1] => Accounts
            [module1_id] => 5a7be8ba-cb0a-2b86-b7da-51e79dc04c79
            [module2] => hotel_booking
            [module2_id] => 379b01fc-9ee9-eb1f-c7c3-51e79d19ccd5
        )

)

Comment: @ajaykumar do one thing as I see anywhere put the double quotation mark in this line `'module1_id' => "$account_id",` and `'module2_id' => "$htel_booking_id",` may be this will be helpful.

Comment: No Luck same output again

Comment: @ajaykumar can you show the other code that you are using to login.

Comment: require_once("./nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");          $soapclient = new nusoap_client('http://xxxx.com/service/v4/soap.php?wsdl',false);
 $soapclient->setCredentials('xxxx','xxxxxx');

 $user_auth = array(
    'user_auth' => array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'password' => md5('admin'),
    'version' => '0.1'
 ),
 'application_name' => 'soapleadcapture');
 

 $result_array = $soapclient->call('login',$user_auth);
 $session_id = $result_array['id'];  this is my login code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer basically set_relationship between custom module is not working as another module

follow the tutorial.

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f148/how-access-custom-module-through-soap-42976/